# Angular loading button ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

I have this component I use in my application and for the most part it works fine.
It's **ts** file looks like this:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { LoadingService } from '@pyb-services/loading.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pyb-loading-button',
  templateUrl: './loading-button.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loading-button.component.scss']
})
export class LoadingButtonComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @Input() link: any[] = []
  @Input() target: string
  @Input() navigateAfter: boolean
  clicked: boolean = false
  loading: boolean = false; // Has to be false by default, because sometimes everything has loaded before this button has come on the page

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private loadingService: LoadingService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingService.onLoadingChanged.subscribe(isLoading => this.loading = isLoading);
  }

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.navigateWhen();
  }

  click(): void {
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    this.navigateWhen();
  }

  private navigateWhen(): void {
    if ((!this.loading || this.navigateAfter) && this.clicked && this.link.length) {
      this.router.navigate(this.link); 

      this.clicked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

And the **template** file looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-xl btn-secondary" type="button" [disabled]="loading && !navigateAfter" (click)="click()" [scrollTo]="target"
  offset="10" [ngSwitch]="loading">
  <span class="spinner" *ngSwitchCase="true">
    <span class="bounce1"></span>
    <span class="bounce2"></span>
    <span class="bounce3"></span>
  </span>
  <span *ngSwitchDefault>Next step</span>
</button>
```

Like I have said, it seems to work fine.
But, if another process kicks off an http request, then I get the error:

> ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'ngSwitch: false'. Current value: 'ngSwitch: true'.

which is moaning about the `loading` property changing in the **loading button** component.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the issue with variable `loading` which is being changed while Change Detection has been trigger. To avoid this error set the value of `loading` in separate thread.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadingService.onLoadingChanged.subscribe(isLoading => 
       Promise.resolve(null).then(() => this.loading = isLoading)
    );
  }
```

Comment: might as wel surround it with a simple setTimeout if you don't want to solve the issue itself..

Comment: That is also doable but not recommendable.